# Is it possible to get a percentage of data, from an OData source, in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, odata

I'm still very new to Power BI, so forgive my possible ignorance.

We need to do a quarterly check-up, on some data.
To get this data, we have an OData endpoint.

Some of the checks require us to get a random sample of data, from within a certain time. 
The random sample of data could be something like: "a random 20% of all papers from 01-01-2020 to 01-02-2020".

I'm not sure if this is possible in Power BI.
If possible, I don't know if I need to adjust my query or do these calculations after getting all the data.

Comment: Can you share an example of input/expected output ?

Comment: @SandraGuilepZouaouiZandeh i'm not quite sure i follow. Input as in my OData query? 

If the scenario would be: "a random 20% of all papers from 01-01-2020 to 01-02-2020", then the output would be something like a table, showing all the fields from these papers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use RAND() in DAX as a calculated column or a measure (RAND in a measure is not always recalculated as it is volatile).

You can add an index column to your table in power query then apply query changes to load the updated table.
Next step , create a measure :

```
ramdom mymeasure = RAND()
```

and add desired fields to a table including the index column that you choose by your logic.
Go to

```
Visualizations pane > Fields > Visual level filters>
Selected Top N under filter type >Show  Top 20 items> Drag random measure to By Value.
```